# Office-Addin MSAL Single Sign In SSO: How to Refresh the Access Token?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-sign-on, office-addins, azure-ad-msal

How does one monitor the access token for expiry and refresh it in an Office-Addin Single Sign on Solution?

MSAL Single Sign On in an Office-Add in is a complicated beast. The access token is obtained by calling:

```
OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()
```

The access token is then swapped for an access token for my API using the Microsoft Identity On-Behalf-Of-Flow. All good.

But access tokens expire. The OfficeRunetime.auth does not appear to have anything that manages the expiry and refresh of access tokens. Unlike its counterpart MsalService (which runs in a normal Javascript/Angular web app - not an Office-Addin) and manages the tokens - and can not be used in an Office-Addin.

Do I simply continue to call OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() in an HTTP Interceptor every time prior to an API call? I understand that getAccessToken() does first consult the cache for an AccessToken, do I infer then that it is managing the expiry of that token and going back to identity server to get a new one?

Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading and prototyping, I'll answer my own question.

Firstly, I am a beginner when it comes to MSAL, tokens, claims, scopes etc and all matters authentication, and I've painfully waddled my way through it all. I welcome all feedback to this answer, and will update the answer if necessary

Here is what I have observed: But firstly, in conclusion to my question

> **OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() manages and refreshes the token when it expires (for MSExcel)**.

**Background**

1. Firstly, I am using MSExcel. The Microsoft Documentation seems to
   group Excel/Word/PowerPoint together and  deals with Outlook
   differently. I am grateful for @Eugene Astafiev answer to this
   question from the Outlook perspective, but I found the opposite to
   be true for Excel
2. The office Add-in *OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()* returns,
   what Microsoft docs calls, a 'bootstrap' token being an access token that also contains an identity token. The bootstrap token can be used in the  On-Behalf-Of Flow (in which it is called the 'assertion' token) to swap it for other access tokens for different scopes. In my app, I swap if for an access token for my API, lets call it the   *APIAccessToken*
3. Both the bootstrap token and the identity token within it expire at
   the same time, after about 87 minutes. The expiry time is recorded
   on the Identity Tokens 'exp' claim. I don't know if this is
   configurable somewhere, but the key is that both expire together.
4. The APIAccessToken (the one returned from the OBO flow) **also** expires at the same time as the bootstrap token (well almost, it seems to expire randomly up to 10 mins after its official expiry time). Every time I call the OBO flow, the generated APIAccesstoken returned is different- but only in the later half of it. Although they are different, and without any regard to what time they were generated, they all still expire at the same time as the bootstrap token (assertion token) that was used to be swapped for them, and they all remain valid, and useable until the expiry time (even though they are different)
5. It is not possible to get the APIAccessToken in any other way in the Excel Addin than using the OBO Flow. This is because of the challenges with IFrames and login redirects in Office Excel. Excel provides the getAccessToken() and a dialog box that runs in its own instance.(see MS Excel docs on Single Sign In for Office-Addin) The access token is only useful for OBO flow
6. The fallback authentication strategy outlined in the MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins is absolutely necessary, as you will always fallback when the user has not granted consent for your SPA and your API to access their profile. However, as currently documented it is not sufficient. It does not get consent for MSOffice15, and this leads to ongoing login problems. I have raised a Stack Overflow question on this here  [Office-Addin Single Sign In, How to manually add MSOffice15 consent and Error 13005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200833/office-addin-single-sign-in-how-to-manually-add-msoffice15-consent-and-error-13) and currently have implemented a work around (I'll post it in response at that link). The fallback must manage three consents. MSOffice15, Your SPA and Your API.

**Refreshing The Token**
1. Every call to  *OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()* returns the same bootstrap token with the same expiry time **until** it expires. When it expires I confirm that this function then calls the Identity Server Endpoint and obtains a new bootstrap token, with a new Identity token, whose expiry time is again ~ 87mins. This makes sense, since the Microsoft Documentation states that it is stored in Cache, and is retrieved by *OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()*. This makes this function call light-weight and can be invoked often.

**MySolution**
I derived a new class (inherited) from the official MSALInterceptor class. On every call to a protected resource I call the *OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()* If the token's expiry date has changed then I know that a new bootstrap token has been issued. I then call some middleware code to get a new APIAccessToken

I hope this saves someone some time! And leaving on a great note, I have finally got the entire Single Sign On login solution working for an Office-Addin SPA (angular)  that manages all consents (office, SPA and my API). Took over 8 weeks work. Now its  Friday 3pm - and I'm sneaking past the boss and going home :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same problem recently too. You (user) must restart Outlook to get a new access token (not expired). Office JavaScript API doesn't provide any method or property for that. The best what you could do is to handle exceptions and notify users to restart the host.

The cache is an in-memory cache. It is only cleared on reboot of Outlook. The tokens will automatically time out after the TTL for the token has expired, but can depend on the server implementation.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not good news though!.  Did you get any sense as to how long the Access Token is live for?. Did you try calling OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() before each API call? I note that if getAccessToken() can not find the key in the cache then it goes to Microsoft Identity Server to refresh the token. Perhaps if I clear this key every period of time, shorter than the access token's life? (I note I am using MSExcel, and Outlook, which you are using, seems to be configured very differently)

Comment: Yes, I call the `getAccessToken` method where required.

Comment: Did allot of work and just posted an answer to my own question, if you are interested

Comment: Good investigation! It seems you have spent a lot of time and efforts for that.

Comment: Eugene Astafiev: I have now discovered that calling getAccesToken() repeatedly from an Excel Office -Addin when using Office on the Web, almost immediacy results in the error code code: 13013.  "This API has been throttled to slow the call frequency." It seems that calling getAccesToken() is not the solution that I posted above. So what do we do? I can't call aquiretokensilent, as its runs in an IFrame and Office on Mac gets upset with that. Other than track the access token expiry time myself, do you have an ideas?