# How could I get a custom API Access Token from Excel Addin aspnetcore project

Tags: access-token, office-addins, azure-ad-msal

I try to use the MS sample Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO
[https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO](https://stackoverflow.com)

I'm trying to access an Azure backend API using the application ID and a specific scope, but it seems that it is not possible using getAccessToken method (refer below link).
How could I proceed?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175583/office-addin-single-sign-on-and-api-scopes](https://stackoverflow.com)

Thanks for your help.

Pete

I tried to add a custom scope when calling getAccessToken
api://zzzzz/c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7 but I didn't get the token for my API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.